# How to make a min : sec count down timer

Tags: javascript, timer

What's wrong with this code? It doesn't display a timer on the page, and when I test it in JSFiddle, I get an "End of Input" syntax error.

```js
$( engage ).click(function () {
 setTimeout(function () {
                    var timeDisplay = document.createElement("p");
                    clock.appendChild(timeDisplay);

                    while (true) {
                        var target = 50 * 60;
                        var curr = target;

                        var x = setInterval(function () {
                            curr -= 1;

                            var mins = Math.floor(curr / 60);
                            var secs = curr % 60;
                            if (secs < 10) {
                                secs = "0" + secs;
                            }

                            console.log(mins + ":" + secs);
                            timeDisplay.innerHTML = mins + ":" + secs;
                        }, 1000);
                    }
                }, 500);
```

Comment: well code is not complete.... and that will loop is bad

Comment: If you click on Run code snippet, it has an error telling you what's wrong.

Comment: A simple search of "[javascript] countdown timer" here on Stack Overflow will produce thousands of results...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so you did the following, but i couldn't understand what you were trying to do. I'd suggest you rename your variables to make yourself understand the code better.

```js
$( engage ).click(function () {
 setTimeout(function () {
                    var timeDisplay = document.createElement("p");
                    clock.appendChild(timeDisplay);

                    while (true) {
                        var target = 50 * 60;
                        var curr = target;

                        var x = setInterval(function () {
                            curr -= 1;

                            var mins = Math.floor(curr / 60);
                            var secs = curr % 60;
                            if (secs < 10) {
                                secs = "0" + secs;
                            }

                            console.log(mins + ":" + secs);
                            timeDisplay.innerHTML = mins + ":" + secs;
                        }, 1000);
                    }
                }, 500);
```

I have the following working code:

```js
function startTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    var h = today.getHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds();
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
   

 console.log(h + ":" + m + ":" + s);
    var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
}
function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
    return i;
}
```